# Why visual studio separates arguments with spaces?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line-arguments

I tried passing 2 arguments in the command line argument in my project like this: argument1, argument2 but later realized that it needs to be like this: argument1 argument2

Why visual studio separates arguments with spaces not with commas? Logically arguments are passed into function which separate their arguments with commas fct(a,b).
I did not know that Visual studio separates arguments with spaces not commas. Why is that?

Comment: Command line arguments are separated by spaces.

Comment: This is determined by the OS (shell), not Visual Studio.

Comment: What does Visual Studio have to do with executing a binary from the command line? I've never seen an application that takes command line parameters in a comma delimited fashion.

Comment: It's a matter of your system's shell. Honestly, I haven't seen one delimiting arguments with characters other than whitespace.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OS shell, I'll look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't only with visual studio. 
Input from the command line always takes its argument delimited by spaces. This is just how it works.

Answer (score 4):

It's got nothing to do with Visual Studio. That's just how *command line arguments* as specified, for all executables, however they were created.

How function parameters are represented and separated in the language used to build the executable is entirely orthogonal to this.